# Using Googles' Noto Color Emoji font in python kivy project

Tags: python, kivy

**Environment:**

- Python 3.10.12
- Packages:
- certifi==2023.11.17
- charset-normalizer==3.3.2
- docutils==0.20.1
- idna==3.6
- Kivy==2.2.1
- Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
- Pygments==2.17.2
- requests==2.31.0
- urllib3==2.1.0

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class CharacterNavigationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10, padding=10)

        self.message_label = Label(text="Navigate the character:")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.message_label)

        # Use the correct font file name
        self.character_label = Label(text="", font_name="NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf", font_size='50sp')
        self.layout.add_widget(self.character_label)

        self.arrow_buttons = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10)

        self.left_button = Button(text="←", on_press=self.move_left)
        self.up_button = Button(text="↑", on_press=self.move_up)
        self.down_button = Button(text="↓", on_press=self.move_down)
        self.right_button = Button(text="→", on_press=self.move_right)

        self.arrow_buttons.add_widget(self.left_button)
        self.arrow_buttons.add_widget(self.up_button)
        self.arrow_buttons.add_widget(self.down_button)
        self.arrow_buttons.add_widget(self.right_button)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.arrow_buttons)

        return self.layout

    def move_left(self, instance):
        self.character_label.x -= 10

    def move_up(self, instance):
        self.character_label.y += 10

    def move_down(self, instance):
        self.character_label.y -= 10

    def move_right(self, instance):
        self.character_label.x += 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CharacterNavigationApp().run()
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Question:**
Why are the character-widget emoji and the arrows in the buttons not displayed? I downloaded the font family file "NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf" and put it in the same directory as the main.py file.